# Annotation exception with Dagger 2

Tags: java, web, dependency-injection, vaadin, dagger-2

I'm trying to integrate Dagger 2 as my dependency injection framework with Vaadin.  However it looks like there is a possible conflict with the Guava version included with Vaadin and Dagger's Guava dependency.  I've narrowed down the build command to `vaadin:compile` in IntelliJ which results in the following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project vaadin: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
[ERROR] Consult the following stack trace for details.
[ERROR] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.filterKeys(Lcom/google/common/collect/SetMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Predicate;)Lcom/google/common/collect/SetMultimap;
```

I've tried changing the scope of Dagger compiler in my build path to `provided` but still encounters the issue.

Is there a way to resolve this compile time issue between Vaadin and Dagger?

Comment: Please, try to exclude lower version old guava dependency. New versions are almost always backwards-compatible.

Comment: The vaadin-client is already set to 'provided' so i'm not sure how i could exclude it any further without breaking Vaadin.

Comment: [Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) is written how to exclude dependency at all. You can view view full tree of dependencies with `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0):

So this is what can happen when you are a mobile dev using Dagger and try switching to web app development with Maven.  I failed to understand / read the instructions for using Dagger 2 with Maven:

> In a Maven project, one would include the runtime in the dependencies
>   section of your pom.xml, and the dagger-compiler artifact as a
>   dependency of the compiler plugin:

Using Gradle, I would place the imports in the same place in the build.gradle.  I finally realized that I needed to add the compiler into separate section of the pom.xml for the maven plugin compiler:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.6</version>
            </dependency>
            **<dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>**
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Lesson learned.